# Xcode build is missing expected TARGET_BUILD_DIR build setting

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, dart

I face error while launching on device `on iPhone 12 Pro Max`. This is console log

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in `debug mode`
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           270.9s
Xcode build is missing expected TARGET_BUILD_DIR build setting.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Answer (score 38):

I just ran into this and fixed it as follows:

- run command `flutter upgrade`
- run command `flutter clean`
- run command `flutter pub get` if you have missing dependencies
- attach phone
- run command `flutter run`

If it still fails, open the Xcode runner project, set your development team and run it directly from there.

After it runs, close Xcode, do a clean build, and run it using your preferred approach.

Comment: No need to call flutter upgrade in my case.

Comment: In my case, After running flutter clean, dependencies were missing so need to run "flutter pub get"

Comment: Thanks @MohamedSaheedMohamedRiswan - have added that to the answer

Comment: In my case I only had to run `flutter run` again for it to work

Answer (score 1):

For me, I noticed my wifi was down so I fixed that, opened ios runner.xcworkspace and ran the project successfully.

Then I closed xCode, and ran my Flutter project again in Android Studio.

Worked.

Comment: Apart from the all the flutter clean, pub get and pod install, flutter run did not work. So I ran the app in the same simulator from Xcode which worked. Then stopped it and ran from VSCode and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is all because of weak or no internet.

Connect your laptop to fast internet and do a flutter clean; flutter pub get and run your app.

Working...