# Flutter Xcode build is missing expected TARGET_BUILD_DIR build setting

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

Xcode build done.                                           958.3s

Xcode build is missing expected TARGET_BUILD_DIR build setting.
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on xyz’s iPhone.

I have tried many ways but could not find proper solutions

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69931437/18627732

Comment: I am getting the same error. Have you found the solution?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**For Anybody Who Experiences this Issue**

In my case, right after getting this error i did a `flutter doctor` to try and understand the problem. That also threw an error indicating that flutter could not reach Maven servers.

So i only had to restart my router or switch my networks to get it working.

This might help.